# Two ui-view in the same page AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, angularjs

I'm new in AngularJs and I have a problem,I have two ui-view in the same page, and when push in the one button for example for show the view goals, appear the form goal in the ui-view 1 and also in the second ui-view at the same time,I worked with states.I don't know how to do for when push one button only show the form belonging to  one ui-view,

look my source:

HTML

```
    <button class="btn btn-success"
    ng-click="go('projectShow.milestones.reports')">New Report</button>

    <div ui-view class="crearreport"></div>


    <button class="btn btn-success"
    ng-click="go('projectShow.milestones.goals')">New Goals</button>

    <div ui-view class="creargoal"></div>
```

Controllerjs:

```
    $scope.go = function(route){ $state.go(route);  };
```

RouteJs:

```
    .state('projectShow.milestones.goals', {
                    templateUrl: '../assets/projects/formulario.html', })           
    .state('projectShow.milestones.reports',{
                        templateUrl: '../assets/reports/formularioReport.html'  })
```

Regards! and thanks for your time !

Comment: can you share your HTML? it would be helpful to see how you are using the ui-view directives

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have multiple ui-view directives you need to give each one a name so you can target them individually.

According to the ui-router wiki

> You can only have one unnamed view within any template (or root html)

```
<!-- Unnamed -->
<div ui-view></div> 

<!-- Named -->
<div ui-view="viewName"></div>
```

There are more details on how to setup ui-router & ui-view here.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-view

Comment: Perfect @jcruz now it works! thanks for your time ! just had to assign name to ui-view, and add the name the view in the state. greetings !